# Excel Interop C# copyRange without shifting

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm trying to copy some columns (with formulas and formats) in an Excel document from one zone to another. The code below does the thing but when I open the document I see that new columns were pasted (old columns are supposed to be rewritten are shifted to the right). The problem is I needed to paste these columns on already existing places without shifting

```
        int lastCol = 15;

        string cC1 = colNumToLetters(lastCol - 3);
        string cC2 = colNumToLetters(lastCol);
        string cI1 = colNumToLetters(lastCol + 1);
        string cI2 = colNumToLetters(lastCol + 4);

        Excel.Range copyRange = sheetPSD.Range[cC1 + ":" + cC2];
        Excel.Range insertRange = sheetPSD.Range[cI1 + ":" + cI2];

        insertRange.Insert(copyRange.Copy());
```

Comment: **insertRange.PasteSpecial(copyRange.Copy());**  - I changed the last string on this and it works correctly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insertRange.PasteSpecial(copyRange.Copy());

Comment: is this the answer ? or a modify about your post ?

Comment: This is an answer

Comment: You should write something to comment that code, nice that you have solve